# How to get HttpContext.Current.Session in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to migrate an MVC project to .net Core, I know it has System.Web removed from ASP.net Core.
I need to convert
HttpContext.Current.Session ["name"]! = Null at asp.net core.
I added: 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
but I have an error.

Comment: a simple google search can give you this information, anyway, it can be accessed with `request.httpcontext` in controllers  and with the word `context` in views

Comment: In the controller it works, but at the service level it does not work.

Comment: @user3296338 services.AddSession();app.UseSession(); added in startup class?

Answer (score 8):

Use like this:

```cs
HttpContext.Session.SetString("priceModel", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customobject));
var priceDetails = HttpContext.Session.GetString("priceModel");
```

Make sure below points in startup class:

1. AddSession in ConfigureServices method

   ```cs
   services.AddSession();
   ```
2. Usesession in configure method:

   ```cs
   app.UseSession();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

you don't have System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session in ASP.NET Core. To access session in non-controller class
step1:
First, register the following service in Startup.ConfigureServices;

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

step2:
register a class (example - TestOrder) where you want to access the Session in

```cs
Startup.ConfigureServices;
services.AddScoped<TestOrder>();
```

Now, in TestOrderclass, add the following code.

```cs
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;    
private readonly ISession _session;    
public TestOrder(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)    
   {    
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;    
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;    
    }
```

The above code is receiving IHttpContextAccessor object through dependency injection and then, it is storing Sessions in a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to register a dependency using the built-in dependency injection container. Inject IHttpContextAccessor into the corresponding service.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void LogCurrentUser()
        {
            var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
            service.LogAccessRequest(username);
        }
    }
```

For more details, refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

Answer (score 0):

Did you test Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1), a sample is like below

```
public const string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
public const string SessionKeyAge = "_Age";
const string SessionKeyTime = "_Time";

 // Requires: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)))
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionKeyAge, 773);
    }

    var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
    var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge);
```

Comment: In the controller it works, but at the service level it does not work