# Session in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core MVC.

In ASP.NET MVC, I am using some `Session` variables to store or get values like:

```
Session["UserID"] = user.UserName;
Session["Role"] = role[0].ROLE_DESCRIPTION;
ViewData["LEVEL"] = Session["LEVEL"];
```

But after converting, I get an error:

> The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

Also, I need to have replacement for this as well in the `.cshtml` file:

```
var UserName = "@Session["Name"]";
```

Is there any other method in ASP.NET Core MVC to store or get values on those variables without changing the behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store and retrieve objects in Session state in ASP.NET Core 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220812/how-to-store-and-retrieve-objects-in-session-state-in-asp-net-core-2-x)

Comment: In addition to the previously asked SO questions, check MSDN [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Is it possible to get and set boolean value from `HttpContext.Session.` for this condition check `if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsSO"]) == true)`

Comment: also for `Session["IsSO"] = "false";`

Comment: Is there any replacement for `Session.Clear()` in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: session working example: https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/770188/Using-Set-or-Get-Session-in-ASPNet-Core-MVC/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add session middleware in your configuration file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
     //........
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();  
    services.AddSession(options => {  
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);//You can set Time   
    });  
    services.AddMvc();  
} 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //......
    app.UseSession();
    //......
}
```

Then in your controller, you can

```
//set session 

HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionName, "Jarvik");  
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionAge, 24);

//get session

ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionName);  
ViewBag.Age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionAge);
```

Comment: How can we get and set boolean value from `HttpContext.Session.`

Comment: I'm afraid you can't set boolean in `HttpContext.Session` directly, you can try `HttpContext.Session.SetString("A", "true");
bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Session.GetString("A"));`

Comment: Thanks. Similarly can we set date as `HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyDate, Start_Date.Date.ToString());`

Comment: Can you help what can be given for "@Session["Name"]"; in .Net core.