# I am trying to implement Sessions in controller of my ASP.NET Core MVC web application but it says "Session" doesnot exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies

> Error: CS0103: The name Session does not exist in the current context

I want to use sessions in my web application to check if user is logged in.

Here is the controller:

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxE98.png)

I have also added the services in `program.cs` file but that doesn't seem to work either.

This is my `program.cs`:

[program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFrB1.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070698/session-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference to this dll `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call HttpContent.Session but it was HttpContext.Session. Thank you for the support