# How to use Session in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

How to use Session in dot net core ?

I wanted to use session tag to store the user id and username when a user is logged in. I am using .net core version 3.1
I have created an Account Controller and in the Login(Post Method) I am trying to use session tag.
Here is the Login Method in AccountController.cs

```
 //POST Login
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(Account user)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var obj = _db.Accounts.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(user.Name) && u.Password.Equals(user.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if(obj != null)
                {
                    Session["Id"] = obj.Id.ToString(); // Error : The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
                    Session["Name"] = obj.Name.ToString(); // Error : The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

I have also used services.AddSession() in ConfigureServices and app.UseSession() in Configure in Startup.cs file
Configure Services in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });

        }
```

Configure in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you just call it like this: `HttpContext.Session` ?

Comment: You appear to be reinventing authentication/authorisation.  Don't use Session, use a JWT bearer token.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220812/how-to-store-and-retrieve-objects-in-session-state-in-asp-net-core-2-x/55221661#55221661

Comment: @RahulSharma That worked but how do I logut from this session, In Isession Interface
HttpContext.Session.Abandon() does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup your `Session` in .NET CORE, you can refer to this S.O [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220812/how-to-store-and-retrieve-objects-in-session-state-in-asp-net-core-2-x/55221661#55221661). Now regarding your question on clearing the `Session`, you can do this:

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

You can read more on the [MSDN](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html?highlight=session)

Comment: How do I access the Session data, i.e, The user details from different controllers and views.
For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739208/how-to-use-session-data-in-a-different-controller-view

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
if(obj != null)
{

   const string userId = "_UserId";
   const string userName = "_UserName";

   HttpContext.Session.SetString(userId, obj.Id.ToString());
   HttpContext.Session.SetString(userName, obj.Name.ToString());

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}
```

You can use this to get it:

```
const string userId = "_UserId";
const string userName = "_UserName";

string user = httpContext.Session.GetString(userId);
string name = httpContext.Session.GetString(userName);
```

Edit #1: TY @Dharman. (copy/pasted TS with tabs/spaces)