# ASP.NET MVC looping through session variable 'List' in the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, drop-down-menu, session-variables

I am setting up an ASP.NET MVC website and I am having a problem looping through a session variable in the client.  The session variable is a List that I want to be a list of sites that will exist in a dropdown list in the navbar on all pages.  So, this will exist within the _Layout.cshtml.  At the moment I am setting the session variables with the HomeController.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564794/is-there-a-way-to-assign-a-list-of-items-to-a-session-and-then-call-it-using-asp) stackoverflow post to get as far as I have done so far. However this post did not deal with displaying the list in the client:

The backend code is below.

**Session Class:**

```
namespace Customer_Application.Models
{
    public class UserSiteList
    {
        public string? Site { get; set; }
        public string? User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SesssionExtensions class:**

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Customer_Application.DataLayer
{
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    string sql = $"SELECT ID FROM [database].[dbo].[tblLogin] WHERE ID = {id}";
    string username = _SharedFunctions.String_Required(sql);

    contxt.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("userID", id);
    contxt.HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", username);

    // Gets the site list for the user and adds to session
    userSiteList = new List<UserSiteList>
    {
        new UserSiteList { Site = "siteA", User = "dave.smith" },
        new UserSiteList { Site = "siteB", User = "dave.smith" }
    };
    contxt.HttpContext.Session.Set<List<UserSiteList>>("userSites", userSiteList);
    var value = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<UserSiteList>>("userSites");

    object Dashboard_inf = new Dashboard();

    return View(Dashboard_inf);
}
```

The value of 'value' is as expected:

[image]

And when returned using the code 'return Json(value)', the follow is returned to the client:

[image]

So I try to use this in the client:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor contxt;

@{
    var userSites = contxt.HttpContext.Session.Get("userSites");
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.
.
.
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 pt-1">
    <li class="nav_item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            Sites
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             @foreach (var item in userSites)
             {
                 <li>@item</li>
             }
        </ul>
    </li>
.
.
```

However this just produces a list of ascii character codes within the drop down list.

[image]

I think that this is something to do with how the 'userSites' variable is assigned in the _Layout.cshtml.  I am pretty sure that '.Get' is incorrect, but do not know how to assign this otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In one code you tell Get what type of object to get, in the other you don’t so it’ll return a string most probably

Comment: "@item.Site" instead of "@item." I wouldn't set it in the HomeController since it's on the shared layout. Render a child and handle populating it inside the child controller so you only have to do it once.

Comment: Thankyou for your responses.  @SamiKuhmonen: not sure what you mean but as you can see from the screen grab that it is a collection that can be enumerated, so I am pretty sure it is not just a string.

Comment: @GH DevOps: In regards to "@item.Site", I have tried that and 'Site' is highlighted as an error with the comment: "CS1061: 'byte' does not contain a definition for 'Site' and no accessible extension method 'Site' accepting a first argument of type 'byte' could be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)".  This is why I believe I have declared the variable incorrectly at the top of _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: You're returning Dashboard_inf instead of userSiteList. Bind your view with userSiteList and "@item.Site" will be available.

Comment: As far as I can tell you cannot mass multiple models to the view in ASP.NET.  and I need dashboard to be passed to the view.  I want the session variable available on all pages, hence why I am setting it up within this method.  whether I should do this elsewhere, is not the issue, I am just trying to get it to work.  As you can see in the HomeController code above, I have set session variables of 'userID' and 'username' which I have successfully displayed in the navbar on all pages following then being set up here.  I want to do the same with the site list as a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass two piece of data you will have to create a ViewMOdel

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public List<UserSiteList>> userSiteList {get; set;}
   public Dashboard dashboard {get;set;}
}
```

now you have to fix your  controller code

```
// comment this code. What is this for?

  //contxt.HttpContext.Session.Set<List<UserSiteList>>("userSites", userSiteList);
//var value = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<UserSiteList>>("userSites");
//
 var model = new ViewModel{
         dashboard = new Dashboard();
         userSiteList= userSiteList
}



    return View(model);
```

and fix a view model, replace

```
@{
    var userSites = contxt.HttpContext.Session.Get("userSites");
}
```

with

```
@model ViewModel
```

and fix this code,should be

```
             @foreach (var item in Model.userSiteList )
             {
                 <li>@item.Site</li>
                   <li>@item.User</li>
             }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  However if I do that, I loose the Dashboard.  I need the Dashboard.

Comment: @Chris What is a Dashboard? I can't see any use

Comment: So the _Layout.cshtml is the master page the deals with the header and footer etc, basically the stuff I want on every page.  I then have a home index.cshtml view that displays the dashboard.  The dashboard is the landing page that displays data the customer is interested in.  A Dashboard object is instantiated from the Dashboard Class and passed to the client to display using @Model.  So you see I need that and I cannot pass another model.  I want the site drop down list to display in the navbar on every page, so I am setting it up as a session variable which can be accessed by all pages

Comment: Thanks for that.  However that would only make it available within that view.  I would have to do the same on every controller.  So really I would like it to be a session variable.

Comment: btw thanks for showing me how I pass multiple models - I will use that elsewhere, but I do not want to use it to solve this issue.

Comment: @Chris You have to google how to create Components.  This is what is used for this case.